# Problems trying to get and pass data from a promise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a job with a colleague, in which he chooses ajax to make requests to a web service, and I use fetch to make a request to an external api, I am running into a problem and it is that at the time of obtaining the data From the api through fetch it brings me the data after a certain time, but when I pass that data through ajax it sends the empty variable, which is logical because the fetch response takes a while to fill my variable, like this that what I try is to put a setTimeout in the ajax to wait a while and that it executes after my fetch request fills the data, but this does not work and does not perform any process:
This is my JavaScript:

```
$("body").on('click', '#MainContent_lnk_actualizar_foto', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let Archivo = $('#MainContent_file_foto')[0].files[0];
    let ubicacion = '';
    let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    let Id_Usuario = params.get('Id_Usuario');
    const datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('imagen', Archivo);
    datos.append('ubicacion', 'perfil');
    fetch(`http://192.168.0.37:52456/api/Archivos/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: datos
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
        .then(response => {
            ubicacion = response.lugar
        })
        
    setTimeout(() => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'WebService_V_Perfil.asmx/SubirArchivos',
            data: '{"Archivo": "' + ubicacion + '","Id_Usuario": "' + Id_Usuario + '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: result => {
                console.log(result);
                console.log(ubicacion);
            }
        })
    }, 3000
});
```

Comment: I see a lot of missing syntax in your snippet. Please verify and fix.

Comment: Instead of guessing how long it will take to get the data, why not just put your ajax call in the `then` function of the `fetch`?

Comment: Well don't use a timeout, just place the code that uses `ubicacion` inside the `.then()` callback!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example also note that your `$.ajax` is outside the `then`

Comment: Btw, don't build JSON by concatenating strings, use `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the syntax errors in your code, the only way you can use the values that return from the `fetch` call is by putting the code that process those results in a `then` block but leave the `catch` block to the end. Otherwise, in this case your code will not run as expected as the second `then()` block is expecting something that the previous `catch()` doesn't return.

```js
fetch(`http://192.168.0.37:52456/api/Archivos/`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: datos
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(response => {
  const ubicacion = response.lugar;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'WebService_V_Perfil.asmx/SubirArchivos',
    data: '{"Archivo": "' + ubicacion + '","Id_Usuario": "' + Id_Usuario + '"}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: result => {
      console.log(result);
      console.log(ubicacion);
    }
  })
})
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
```

Also, I don't think you need to use `ajax` to do what the same task as `fetch` does.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I forgot the `const`.